# Can i run ubuntu 12.04 using live cd if I still have ubuntu 11.10 installed on my Pc?

Tags: live-cd

I already have Ubuntu 11.10 installed. I have used Wubi to install it. I want to know is it safe or okay to use Ubuntu live cd of 12.04 LTS to test the new functionalities without modifying or changing anything of current Ubuntu installation ?

Comment: live CD doesn't change/affect your current installation unless  you command it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For faster loading even u can try with live USB, you can also create a small home folder(Persistance), to keep some personal files. This also doesn't touch your current install.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can. When using the live cd it won't touch your current install.